# How to get inverse of a complex double matrix using Eigen library?

Tags: c++, matrix, eigen3, matrix-inverse

I tried to a cpp program to find inverse of a 10 by 10 `covariance matrix` 'sn' [where sn=x*x^H; H is hermitian ] of data type complex double with `Eigen library`. Since sn has rank 2, I tried to make it a full rank matrix by adding a 10 by 10 matrix 'a' whose diagonal elements are 0.01 and off diagonal elemennts are 0. But now when I use `.inverse()`, it gives wrong results on comparing with MATLAB.

```
int main()
{
MatrixXcd sn(10,10),sn1(10,10),a(10,10);
for(i=0;i<10;i++)
   for(j=0;j<10;j++)
      if(i==j)
      a(i,j)=0.01;
sn1=sn+a;//sn is known
cout<<"sn1 inverse"<<sn1.inverse()<<endl;
 }
```

When I tried to find inverse of a simple matrix of order 2 by 2 , inverse() worked perfectly. Please help me.

Comment: You can check whether the result you get is wrong by multiplying 
`sn1.inverse() * sn1`. Also, are you sure `sn1` does have the inverse matrix?

Comment: Do you know `x` (from which `sn=x*x^H` was generated)? In that case it could be a good idea to compute the QR decomposition of `x` instead. For semi-definite selfadjoint matrices, the `LDLT` decomposition would often be better than the (default) LU decomposition.

Comment: N.B.: Your code to generate `a` is wrong: You don't set the off-diagonal entries to 0 (they are therefore uninitialized). Better simply write `sn1 = sn + 0.01 * MatrixXcd::Identity(10,10);`